# Popup for notifying a user on Android

Tags: php, javascript, android, jquery, html

I have made a website and I have an android app for it. The site is made in PHP/HTML. And i dont know much about javascript or jquery.

I have an android app which i want users to be notified if they open it on their mobile.

So, can someone help me with the code which i need to use so that people who use android when they come to my website will be notified via a pop-up that there is an android app available. Help me out please.

I need to know basically how can i detect if the user is using an android device and how to send him a popup.

Comment: Rather than a popup why not just add a section to the top of the page. As an android user nothing annoys me more than a full screen notification of a specific app for a specific site, I will never download it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This really helped me:
[Detect Android](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-android)
Take a look at that and let me know if is that what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

No javascript required if you don't want to

```
$ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
if(stripos($ua,'android') !== false) { // && stripos($ua,'mobile') !== false) {
    // user is on an android device.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid) {
    // Do something!
    // Show message about android app
    alert("We have an android app, download it now!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For detecting what device the user is using, [this will probably help you out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery). However, I have to agree with Jared's comment and discourage you from using a pop-up. A top-of-the-page banner is fine, but having a pop-up saying "HEY, DOWNLOAD THIS APP!" really ruins the user experience in my opinion.